# Using Spark 3.2 to ingest IoT data into delta lake continuously

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, parquet, delta-lake

It is possible to use `org.apache.spark.sql.delta.sources.DeltaDataSource` directly to ingest data continuously in append mode ?

Is there another more suitable approach? My concern is about latency and scalability since the data acquisition frequency can reach 30 KHz in each vibration sensor and there are several of them and I need to record the raw data in Delta Lake for FFT and Wavelet analysis, among others.

In my architecture the data ingestion is done continuously in a Spark application while the analyzes are performed in another independent Spark application with on-demand queries.

If there is no solution for Delta Lake, a solution for Apache Parquet would work because it will be possible to create Datasets in Delta Lake from data stored in Parquet Datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and it works well. There are several advantages of Delta for streaming architecture:

- you don't have a "small files problem" that often arises with streaming workloads - you don't need to list all data files to find new files (as in case of Parquet or other data source) - all data is recorded in the transaction log
- your consumers don't see partial writes because Delta provides transactional capabilities
- streaming workloads are [natively supported by Delta](https://docs.delta.io/latest/delta-streaming.html)
- you can perform DELETE/UPDATE/MERGE even for streaming workloads - it's impossible with Parquet

P.S. you can just use `.format("delta")` instead of full class name

Comment: thank you very much @Alex Ott for the "natively supported by Delta" link. It was clear how to I should implement the solution.

Comment: I still have a doubt. In the examples I saw with Apache Streaming, Kafka or Kinesis is used. In my case I have my own distributed event bus and I will need to create a driver to Spark Streaming using Java Socket and deploy it adding the corresponding artifact spark-streaming-my-iot-dbus-drive_2.12 to the dependencies. I see some examples using Socket but with messages in text format. For me binary format is more appropriate. Is it possible ?

Comment: format of a payload - it's your own decision, it's really a contract between producers & consumers.  Many people are using Avro for such things.  Regarding use of Kafka or Kinesis - it's really depends on your requirement. Usually they are used as kind of buffer that allows to receive messages at higher rates (I saw Cassandra as well), and then processed by slightly slower, but more scalable systems like, Spark. From your question it wasn't clear that Spark will be a direct receiver. If you have an event bus, I would plug spark directly into it instead of using Sockets

Comment: Hi @Alex Ott, I implemented the solution but I am experiencing a strange problem. I created a question in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70762808/.  Maybe you can see if you find something wrong. I've already burned my neurons and I can't find the problem.